# how to make horizontally Screenfit Imageview which is between cardview

Tags: android

i am making a app in my app there is i am using cardview between my cardview there is a image view i want to make my image-view screen-fit horizontally.
can any one tell me how i achieve this

following is my layout code

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/CardView_Id"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.93"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBottomNavigation">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="315dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp">


            <!--<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="MOBILE RECHARGE"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_deal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/p1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Try this -  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: RelativeLayout has no closing tag in your code. If you want the imageview inside relative layout, use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true", if you want to remove the the RelativeLayout, use gravity="center_horizontal". And off course the imageview will fit only within the 400dp of its cardview layout.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use fixed size about width,if you let width match parent,it will always be matching with the width of device screen.This will make your image fit horizontally:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/CardView_Id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_deal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/p1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```